# Outbound Twilio SMS to group - Will send to some, but not all

Tags: groups, sms, twilio

We have Twilio SMS set up and it works great for the most part.

The issue we are having, however, is trying to send to a group of contacts.  The group has 137 individual contacts in it.  When I try to set up the SMS to the group, it picks 25 contacts that it can send to and displays an error message at the top that says:  "SMS will NOT be sent to 112 contacts - (no phone number on file, or communication preferences specify DO NOT SMS, or contact is deceased)."

Here is what I have done to troubleshoot this:

- All of the contacts in the group have their communication preferences such as it will allow SMS; in other words, DO NOT SMS is not checked for any of the contacts in the group
- All of the contacts have a mobile phone number in their record. The records that do work have a work mobile and the records that do not work have a work mobile.
- None of the contacts are deceased
- I have selected several contacts that it says it cannot send to and tried to send them an individual SMS which works.
- It clearly is not close to the 200/day limit.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an old version of CiviCRM, before 5.49? It looks like this was [fixed in 5.49](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23166).

Comment: Yes, I am using 5.463. Thanks for your response.